# Show that $(E\cup Z_1)\setminus Z_2$ has the form $E\cup Z$

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to do an exercise as follows:

> Let $(X, {\mathbf X}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let ${\mathbf Z}=\{E\in {\mathbf X}:\mu(E)=0\}$. Let $\mathbf X'$ be the family of all subsets of $X$ of the form $(E\cup Z_1)\setminus Z_2, E\in \mathbf X$, where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are arbitrary subsets of sets belonging to $\mathbf Z$. Show that a set is in $\mathbf X'$ if and only if it has the form $E\cup Z$ where $E\in \mathbf X$ and $Z$ is a subset of a set in $\mathbf Z$.

My proposed answer was if $Q=E\cup Z$ where $E\in \mathbf X$ and $Z\subset P\in\mathbf Z$ then $Q=E\cup Z\setminus(P\setminus Z)$ since $Z$ and $P\setminus Z$ are both subsets of $P\in \mathbf Z$. This seems to be wrong since it assumes $P\cap E=\emptyset$. Also, I cannot seem to work out how to go the other way around. I tried defining the set $R=\{x\in X:f(x)>0\}$. By the definition of sigma algebra, $R\in \mathbf X$. Then I tried taking intersections and complements with $R$. However I just keep getting messy expressions which never resolve to the required $E\cup Z$. Is this method with $R$ a good idea or did I miss something obvious?

[This is part of exercise 3.L. of *The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure* by R. G. Bartle.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $E \cup Z = (E \cup Z) \setminus \emptyset \in \mathbf X'$.

On the other hand, suppose that $E \in \mathbf X$, $N_1,N_2 \in \mathbf Z$, $Z_1 \subset N_1$, and $Z_2 \subset N_2$.

Now work out that $$(E \cup Z_1) \setminus Z_2 = (E \setminus N_2) \cup \bigg[(E \cap (N_2 \setminus Z_2)) \cup (Z_1 \setminus Z_2)\bigg]$$ 
which belongs to $\mathbf X'$, since the set in brackets is a subset of $N_1 \cup N_2$.

Comment: $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are subsets of sets in $\mathbf Z$, not members of it. If $N_2\in\mathbf X$ and $\mu(N_2)=0$ then $N_2\in\mathbf Z$. It is not clear to me how you can be sure we can construct $N_2$ (why such a set exists in $\mathbf X$).

Comment: OK for every $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, $\{x\in X:f(x)\leq\alpha$ belongs to $\mathbf X$, so if $\alpha=0$ we can construct $N_2$ as this set and $Z_2\subset N_2$ and $\mu(N_2)=0$, is that what you meant?

Comment: In the notation of my question, $N_2=R^c$ so $(E\cap R)\cup[(E\cap R^c\cap Z_2^c)\cup (Z_1\setminus Z_2)]$. The point I missed was to use the fact that $R^c\in \mathbf Z$ as I noticed from my comment above.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote that wrong. It seems easier to use $\mathbf Z$ to describe the subsets of sets of measure zero, but that's not how you defined it.

Comment: Thank you for responding and editing the post. I copied the question word-for-word from the book, this is exactly what it says.

Answer (score 0):

The "if" part in my view is trivial, if you consider $Z_1=Z$ and $Z_2=\emptyset$.

The "only if" part is non-trivial. First Let $X=\left(E\cup Z_1\right)\backslash Z_2$. Pick an increasing sequence $\left(X_i\right)\in \bf{X}$ such that $X_i\subset X$ for all $i\geq1$ and $\mu\left(X_i\right)\rightarrow\mu\left(E\right)$ as $i\rightarrow\infty$. This is possible because $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are null sets. (You can prove this claim.) Then, define $E^\prime=\bigcup_{i\geq1}X_i$ and $Z^\prime=X\backslash E^\prime$. We then have all the desired properties: $E^\prime\cup Z^\prime=E$ (since $E^\prime \subset X$), $E^\prime \in \bf{X}$, and $Z^\prime$ is a subset of a set in $\bf{Z}$ (for the last claim I give a proof below).

Claim: $Z^\prime$ is a subset of a set in $\bf{Z}$.

Note that $Z^\prime = X\backslash E^\prime = \left(E\cup Z_1\right)\backslash Z_2 \backslash E^\prime $. Let $P_1\in\bf{Z}$ such that $Z_1\subset P_1$. Then, $Z^\prime = \left(E\cup Z_1\right)\backslash Z_2 \backslash E^\prime \subset \left(E\cup P_1\right)\backslash E^\prime \in \bf{X}$. So it now only remains to prove that $\left(E\cup P_1\right)\backslash E^\prime \in \bf{Z}$. This is simple computation from now on! $\mu\left(\left(E\cup P_1\right)\backslash E^\prime\right)=\mu\left(E\cup P_1\right)-\mu\left(\left(E\cap E^\prime\right)\cup \left(P_1\cap E^\prime\right)\right)=\mu\left(E\right)-\mu\left(E^\prime\right)=0$. So the claim is true indeed.

Comment: I am still thinking about this one, sorry my knowledge is a bit primitive for your arguments.

Comment: I realised the arguement can be a lot simpler than this. Appologies that there were some unnecessary complexity. One can just consider E'=X\P_1 where P_1 is a zero measure set containing Z_1. Then define Z'=X\E'. Then one can continue from the sentence "we then have all the desired properties"....